# Apply List.flatten to a Stream

Tags: stream, elixir

The following pipe:

```
items
...
|> Stream.map(&process/1)
```

Generates this kind of structure:

```
[ [], [], [], [] ]
```

and I would like it to be a flatten list.

Without using streams I would just do:

```
|> Enum.map(&process/1)
|> List.flatten
```

But I would like to use it as a stream but cant figure out how to apply List.flatten and generate a Stream.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could try using [`Stream.flat_map/2`](https://hexdocs.pm/elixir/Stream.html#flat_map/2), something this should help:

```
items
...
|> Stream.flat_map(&process/1)
```

This will keep processing `element`s in your `items`, and `flatten` the results.

Hope that helps!